# Erwin commuity editon and ms-access

Tags: ms-access, vba, erwin

I am looking for examples or tips related to developing logical and physical data models and to forward engineer same to MS Access. In r9 of the community edition, there is no output specific for Access.
I'm hoping someone has an example (vba) for going from the physical model and the script file generated  to actually loading the info into  Access.

I am aware of the youtube videos re Erwin but have not found an example.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"there is no output specific for Access"* - The product description page [here](http://erwin.com/products/data-modeler/community-edition) says that it supports ODBC, so does it offer an output for ODBC?

Comment: Thanks for your response.Yes, it offers output to ODBC. However, I don't have specifics on getting that info into Access. I am looking for a tutorial/guidance, preferably an example, to get the info from logical to  physical database  and into Access.

Comment: Since ERWin dropped support of their Community Edition, I have found and downloaded TOAD data modeler  (free edition limited functionality). It does allow generation of Access tables  from  data model.